# writing to and reading from a file simultaneous

Tags: android

I'm trying to read from a file while it still opened for witing.
How it can be done?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html